# How to join multiple csv uploads (by different machines) in Google Storage into one final file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

We have multiple machines each processing a subset of problems and each exporting a chunk csv file. We want one final csv file that would be a join of all the chunk files, but we do not have one final process running after all the machines are done. Essentially, we'd like to have each machine append to a file, but they're on google cloud storage.

We're thinking of different approaches - maybe using pub/sub to append to a file every time it receives a set of rows?

I've seen the compose operation but it needs to be run once all files have uploaded, which again would require a final step.

Any suggestions would be welcome, this will be one final file of about 500k rows and we're talking a few chunks, up to 10 perhaps.

Comment: What is the total size? Is the CSV format could be loaded in database (each chunk have the same number of column and the order is the same)?

Comment: It's about 20 columns and each chunk would have the same structure, so it could be loaded into a DB.

Answer (score 0):

I’d go for having a pubsub topic to append a file, by the [compose](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/compose), every time you’ve got a set of rows.

This task can be perform as a final step but you can also think it as a pair composing task, you would just have to validate that the pubsub topic is not executed twice since this can happen and its adviced [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/faq#duplicates)

Comment: Yeah I think that's where we're going to go. Any clever tricks to avoid the header row being repeated?

Comment: I’d go for creating a new name for the composed object with ids concatenation, the [object name](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#object-names) can be up to 1024 bytes UTF8 encoded chars, you could be using [1 byte chars](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_basic_latin.asp) and that would result in a maximum of ~59 bytes per id, fair enough I think.

Comment: You can apply the name validation into a cloud function with a [bucket trigger for new objects](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#object_finalize).

Comment: It's not possible to delete headers in each file. Compose is basic: it basically appends files, no more. The best way is to produce file without header.